# Command --auth not for working on Mongo 5

Tags: mongodb, docker

I was using Mongo 4 for my application, setting it up with docker-compose, from the image mongo:4.0, where I used the `--auth` argument to indicate we need authentication.

Now I'm migrating to Mongo5, and when I run something like

`docker run -d --rm -p 27017:27017   --name mongo1  --network mongoCluster mongo:5.0 mongod --replSet replicaset --bind_ip localhost,mongo1 --auth`

it fails silently (I don't see the docker running with an error, or the docker in a failed status, neither with `docker ps` nor `docker ps -a` it's just gone).

However, `docker run -d --rm -p 27017:27017  --name mongo1  --network mongoCluster mongo:5.0 mongod --replSet replicaset --bind_ip localhost,mongo1`

works perfectly (except for the fact that my application has authentication problems afterwards)

What am I doing wrong? Has the authentication command that is needed changed for Mongo5 maybe?